# C# Reading a raw pastebin by lines

Tags: c#, pastebin

I would like to know how or if it's possible to read a pastebin's individual lines using C#. I want to read the lines of http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fTgJF857 and check if the text within each line matches another string. Is this possible/How can I do it?

My goal is to compare the user's ID to a list of IDs. Kind of like a whitelist. Something like this:

`if(linefrompastebin == useridstring)
    {
     _isAllowed = true
    }`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `HttpWebRequest` (or `WebClient` or `HttpClient` depending on the current phase of the moon) to request the text from PasteBin
2. Capture the stream (`GetResponseStream`) and read from it character-by-character using `StreamReader` or cheat by using the client's logic to save it to a string and then hackishly call `String.Split`

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know how I could compare the string to another string like:`if(strings == "987654321")` and is it possible to make it only run once?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The code reads lines of HTML from  `http://pastebin.com/raw.ph ?i=fTgJF857` , stores the data in a string array and checks  line by line  to see  if the text within each line matches a reference string.

```
using  System;
using  System.Net;
using  System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication5{
    class Program    {
        static void Main(string[] args){                
            string[] linefrompastebin = new string[100];
            string useridstring = "76561198079483032";
            int i = 0;
            int maxLines = 0;
            bool _isAllowed = false;

            var url = "http://pastebin.com/raw/fTgJF857";
            var client = new WebClient();

            Console.WriteLine("Reading HTML at :  http://pastebin.com/raw/fTgJF857 \n\n");

            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            linefrompastebin[0] = "";

            //Store lines from HTML into string
            while ((linefrompastebin[i] = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
                i++;
            }
            maxLines = i;
            }

            //do some line processing - compare user with whitelist
            for (i = 0; i < maxLines;i++ ){
                Console.WriteLine(linefrompastebin[i]);

                if(linefrompastebin[i] == useridstring){
                    _isAllowed = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("_isAllowed = true on -> "+ linefrompastebin[i]+ ". user Exists in database");
                 }

            }

            linefrompastebin = null;
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```